# Generate nodes.pp using hiera in puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a environment that has several environments like production staging etc . Now what i want is that I can re-use the **nodes.pp** written for one environment  for the other.

Example - Suppose I have 2 environment production and staging. Each contains a web server. Now if I already have nodes.pp (or some other manifests ) written for a node in a environment, how to use hiera-puppet to generate this nodes.pp according to the environment.

```
+++
++++Production 
+--------------server1-production
+--------------server2-production
++++Staging
+--------------Staging-web1  (Needs the same classes as server1-production)
+--------------Staging-web2  (Needs the same classes as server2-production)
```

Comment: The accepted practice is to use standard puppet manifests and have environment specific data in hiera. See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/complete_example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link. It may be the paradigm you are looking for.

http://www.craigdunn.org/2012/05/239/